# Python celery backend/broker access via ssh

Tags: python, ssh, rabbitmq, celery

Im using an sql server and rabbitmq as a result backend/broker for celery workers.Everything works fine but for future purposes we plan to use several remote workers on diferent machines that need to monitor this broker/backend.The problem is that you need to provide direct access to your broker and database url , thing that open many security risks.Is there a way to provide remote celery worker the remote broker/database via ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like ssh port forwarding is working but still i have some reservations.
My plan works as follows:

1. port forward both remote database and broker on local ports(auto
   ssh) in remote celery workers machine.
2. now celery workers consuming the tasks and writing to remote database from local ports port forwaded.

Is this implementations bad as noone seems to use remote celery workers like this.
Any different answer will be appreciated.